# View not renders new variable change Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am working on ready project, sorry but not able to share plunk or smthn, will try my best to explain. As you can see from the picture whenever user clicks menu on the left side every component that shows up in router-outlet changes section name on init just by emiting new sectionName and its visibility like below:

```
{
    name: 'Home',
    isVisible: true,
}
```

and there is subscriber to get and change section name and its visibility :

```
 current_section: {} = {
    name: 'Home',
    isVisible: true,
  };
 this._dashboardService.current_section.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.current_section = data;
        console.log(data);
      }
 );
```

//Template side of section name

```
<div *ngIf="current_section.isVisible" class="hide-on-print">
                <h2 class="display-4">
                    {{current_section?.name}}
                </h2>
                <hr>
</div>
```

//how router-outlet components set section name (for example home page below)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._dashboardService.current_section.next({ name: 'Home', isVisible: true });
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Whenever route changes to another component it set new value to section but ui not rendering for the first time. But it works fine if I remove ngif from template side of section_name like below

```
 //<div *ngIf="current_section.isVisible" class="hide-on-print">
                    <h2 class="display-4">
                        {{current_section?.name}}
                    </h2>
                    <hr>
    //</div>
```

[image]

as additional info:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
node: 6.10.3
os: darwin x64
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
@angular/common: 4.3.2
@angular/compiler: 4.3.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.2
@angular/core: 4.3.2
@angular/forms: 4.3.2
@angular/http: 4.3.2
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.2
@angular/router: 4.3.2
```

Comment: Most likely because `current_section` is null. Check for `current_section` is not null first then `current_section.isVisible`. Or do `current_section?.isVisible`

Comment: I've tried it, no changes

Comment: There is 1 interesting thing,  it changes (works ok) after you click same routerLink (menu) for the second time

Comment: I have had this problem with observables before.  It has something to do with obersvable, class initilization and ngOnInit() but I cannot remember how to solve it.  I think in order to fix it I had to subscribe to the on route change event.

Comment: Try manually triggering change detection after your click event. You can use `ChangeDetectorRef` and `detectChanges()`

Comment: @thomasmeadows pls remember it, man :D

Comment: @AJT_82 using it gave 'ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.' in another component but when I delete it works without error. I have checked all the possibilities for this error but nothing s changed.

Comment: Well, apparently you have a form in your code that we know nothing about :D

Comment: @AJT_82 no as I mentioned it is in different component , in one of the router-outlet components, but it works fine and there is not any initialization error when I remove detectChanges()